# Pandas: sort values keeping the one particular value at the bottom

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a list:

```
car_name             value  
Car1                 1000
Car2                 1002
Car3                 1033
Car1                 1046
Car2                 1800
Car3                 1009
...                  ...
Carn                  n
Other                7500
```

What I need is to do merging of the similar cars and sorting by value, keeping "Other" always at the bottom.

So far my code is:

```
df=df.groupby('car_name').sum().sort_values(value)
```

How to add this "other" condition?

Comment: Does this work? `df=df.groupby(by='car_name', sort=False).sum().sort_values(value)`

Comment: What value do you want to sort by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows can be easily rearranged using [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on separate components. I don't think there is such option om `df.sort_values()` which can set an element at the bottom directly.

```
df = df.groupby('car_name').sum().sort_values("value")
pd.concat([df[df.index != "Other"], df[df.index == "Other"]])

          value
car_name       
Car3       2042
Car1       2046
Car2       2802
Other      7500
```

Alternatively, not setting `car_name` as index:

```
df = df.groupby('car_name', as_index=False).sum().sort_values("value")
pd.concat([df[df["car_name"] != "Other"], df[df["car_name"] == "Other"]])

  car_name  value
2     Car3   2042
0     Car1   2046
1     Car2   2802
3    Other   7500
```